# ripgreb: show search result between two hits

Tags: regex, ripgrep

I'm very new to ripgreb, but very impressed by it.

I have a very special triggy case that I was wondering if could be done

Say I have two markdown files

```
...
## 5.9 Subheading

plz, plz, plz do NOT find me!

# 6 Heading

## 6.1 subheading

plz, plz, plz FIND me!

## 6.2 subheading

plz, plz, plz do NOT find me!
...
```

and

```
...

## 6.1 subheading

plz, plz, plz FIND me too!

## 6.2 subheading

plz, plz, plz do NOT find me too!
...
```

Would it be possible to search within `## 6.1` and `## 6.2` for lines with more than one comma per line?

So it displayed something like this

```
$rg <magic-search term>

221 plz, plz, plz FIND me!

256 plz, plz, plz FIND me too!
```

Currently I just do this to see it

```
rg '## 6.1' --before-context 0 --after-context 4
```

but that does not search for multiple commas after '## 6.1' or limit the search to be after

---

## UPDATE

I found a "solution" for **ripgrep** and just dropping it here:

```
$rg '## 6.1.*## 6.2' --multiline --multiline-dotall 

220 ## 6.1 subheading
221 plz, plz, plz FIND me!
222 ## 6.2 subheading

255 ## 6.1 subheading
256 plz, plz, plz FIND me too!
257 ## 6.2 subheading
```

Currently it also prints out the headers (`## 6.1` and `## 6.2`)

Trying to avoid that by doing something like this but that just removes this first `#` and not the entire line

```
$rg '(?:(?!## 6.1).)*## 6.2' --multiline --multiline-dotall --pcre2

220 # 6.1 subheading
221 plz, plz, plz FIND me!
222 ## 6.2 subheading

255 # 6.1 subheading
256 plz, plz, plz FIND me too!
257 ## 6.2 subheading
```

---

Thanks goes to [chriserin](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/9zneks2cbv-multiline-matches-with-ripgrep-rg)

Comment: Also kindly do add your sample of expected output too along with with anubhava sir mentioned to add so that we get a clear picture of your question too.

Comment: @anubhava I tried to update my question to  your comments

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I tried to update my question to  your comments

Comment: But `256 plz, plz, plz FIND me too!` is not even there in input data

Comment: @anubhava added it now

Comment: Try this awk: `awk -F, '/^## 6\.1 /{p=1; next} /^## 6\.2 /{p=0} p && NF > 1' file`

Comment: that is beautiful! @anubhava - how do I implement this into ripgreb or do it on all files in a directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217762/discussion-between-norfeldt-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F, '/^## 6\.1 /{p=1; next} /^## 6\.2 /{p=0} p && NF > 1' file
```

Flag `p` will be set to `1` when we encounter `## 6.1` and will be reset when we encounter `## 6.2`.

To use with wildcards that also prints filenames:

```
awk -F, '/^## 6\.1 /{p=1; next} /^## 6\.2 /{p=0}
  p && NF > 1{print FILENAME ":", $0}' *
```